AWS Lambda Init Duration is High Despite Using Provisioned Concurrency
I'm experiencing an issue with my AWS Lambda function where the Init Duration is significantly high, even though I've configured Provisioned Concurrency. The function's actual execution time is around 579.01 ms, but the Init Duration in CloudWatch logs is 11190.69 ms.
Here's the relevant part of my SAM template:
GetRecommendedTales:
  Type: 'AWS::Serverless::Function'
  Properties:
    Handler: recommended_tales.get_recommended_tales_pagination
    CodeUri: ai_tale_teller/
    Runtime: python3.9
    AutoPublishAlias: V1
    ProvisionedConcurrencyConfig:
      ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions: 1
    Policies:
      - AmazonDynamoDBFullAccess
    Events:
      GetRecommendedTalesEvent:
        Type: Api
        Properties:
          Path: /recommended-tales
          Method: GET
          RestApiId: !Ref TalesApi

And here is the Lambda function code:
from gpt import generate_tale
from translations import get_messages
TALE_TABLE_NAME = os.environ['TALE_TABLE_NAME']
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table(TALE_TABLE_NAME)

def get_recommended_tales_pagination(event, context):
    try:
        print("Started")
        limit = int(event['queryStringParameters'].get('limit', 5))
        last_evaluated_key = event['queryStringParameters'].get('lastEvaluatedKey', None)

        title = event['queryStringParameters'].get('title', None)
        language = event['queryStringParameters'].get('language', None)
        age = event['queryStringParameters'].get('age', None)

        # Build filter expression and attribute values
        filter_expression, expression_attribute_values = build_filter_expression(title, language, age)

        # Add TaleType value to expression attribute values
        if expression_attribute_values is None:
            expression_attribute_values = {}
        expression_attribute_values[":type_val"] = {"S": "Recommended"}

        query_params = {
            'TableName': RECOMMENDED_TALE_TABLE_NAME,
            'IndexName': 'TaleTypeCreatedAtIndex',  # GSI name
            'KeyConditionExpression': "TaleType = :type_val",
            'ExpressionAttributeValues': expression_attribute_values,
            'ScanIndexForward': False,  # To sort by latest CreatedAt
            'Limit': limit
        }

        # Add filter expression if it exists
        if filter_expression:
            query_params['FilterExpression'] = filter_expression

        if last_evaluated_key:
            query_params['ExclusiveStartKey'] = json.loads(last_evaluated_key)

        items, next_token, end_of_data = get_paged_data("query", query_params, last_evaluated_key)

        return {
            "statusCode": 200,
            "body": json.dumps({
                'Items': items,
                'LastEvaluatedKey': next_token
            }),
            "headers": {
                'Content-Type': 'application/json'
            }
        }
    except Exception as e:
        print(f"Exception occurred: {str(e)}")
        raise

I've set ProvisionedConcurrentExecutions to 1 in my SAM template, assuming it would keep a warm instance ready, but I'm still seeing very high Init Duration times.
What could be causing this high initialization time, and how can I reduce it?


ReservedConcurrentExecutions if you set 1 it will only handle one request

It's just for testing.

You haven't shown what your code is doing outside of the function handler, which is the largest contributor to the INIT phase duration.

I've just added. TALE_TABLE_NAME = os.environ['TALE_TABLE_NAME']
dynamodb = boto3.resource("dynamodb")
table = dynamodb.Table(TALE_TABLE_NAME) @jarmod

And your imports?

I added them too @jarmod

Do you know how long those 2 imports take to execute? Have you timed them individually? Other than that, there's no reason that I can see from your code why your INIT duration would be 11 seconds. If you deploy an absolutely minimal function, including just your imports and the code outside of your function handler plus a debug statement to ensure it's actually this code that's running, what is the INIT duration? It might be worth making a support request to AWS here.

Please check a few things:

You are not using $LATEST version of any function, because AWS link


You cannot use provisioned concurrency with the $LATEST version of any function.
If your function has an event source, make sure that event source points to the correct function alias or version. Otherwise, your function won't use provisioned concurrency environments.


Call your lambda like LambdaName:version
Eg: YourLambdaName:1, instead of just YourLambdaName.

Please see this answer SO Answer from user @marco-roy



I am sure that, I'm not using LATEST version. I've just added an attachment for that
